# Do I need to use a resistor with a microswitch to limit current for an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, current, resistors, switches

I'm using an Arduino Uno to control a small robot and I'm starting to add micro-switches as bump-sensors. I know that when I'm creating a circuit with LEDs I need to use resistors to limit the current so I don't mess up the Arduino, but do I need to do the same with the micro-switches? If so, how do I calculate the necessary resistance?

If it makes a difference, my micro-switch is Pololu #1405, Snap-Action Switch with 15.6mm Bump Lever 3-pin, SPDT, 5A. The Arduino outputs 5V and has a maximum of 40mA.

**EDIT**: I've done some more research and I found a page that seems to describe exactly what I want to do (http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/button), don't know how I missed it before. So if I'm understanding the situation correctly, the only resistor I need is the pull-up/down one between the switch and ground, but none between the switch and the pin that's reading the switch.

Comment: Generally you do use resistors, but for a different purpose - as pull-ups or pull-downs. As Olin says, schematic needed: http://www.w9xt.com/page_microdesign_pt6_switch_inputs.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need a resistor, as long as you set up the pin to be **input**. The current protection resistors are necessary only in cases where the Arduino pin is used as a current source, i.e. **output**. If the pin is used as an output pin, you may need a current-limiting resistor, depending on what is connected to the pin.  *Usually* we don't connect switches to outputs though (except for unusual cases when the switches need power, switches are actually circuits, etc).

For an input pin you may want a pull-up or a pull-down resistor. However, all AVR chips have built-in pull-ups. After you configured the pin as an input pin, you activate the pull-up resistor by `digitalWrite(HIGH)` to that pin, or, as **@mpflaga** points out, on the newer Arduino toolchain, you can set the input mode and pullup using `pinMode(in_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);` line. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7423/what-is-a-pull-up-and-pull-down) for more information on pull-up/pull-down resistors.

If you want a discrete pull-up resistor (i.e. not use the built-in one, though I don't know why you would do that) the circuit would look as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEteSa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The pin will read high when the switch isn't pressed, and low when it is.

Comment: Note latest Arduino IDE has a pinmode command to make it more clear. pinMode(in_pin,  INPUT_PULLUP);  http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PinMode

Comment: Ah, cool. That's much clearer than the `digitalWrite(..)` version of that same. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A closed switch is a dead short.  Analyze your circuit by replacing all the switches with shorts.  If all the currents are still within spec, then you're fine.  If not, you're not.

Without a schematic or any hint of what exactly you are doing, this is about all that can be said.