# Why place large resistor from gate to ground of MOSFET?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, transistors, mosfet

As I was learning about MOSFETS today, I noticed that nearly every circuit diagram with a MOSFET features a large pulldown resistor placed in parallel to the transistor.

[image]

For example, in this picture we can observe that a extremely large, 1 Mega Ohm resistor is placed parallel to our mosfet. While I understand that this resistor exists to primarily ground out any floating charges on the wire, I don't quite understand why the resistor is usually so large. Why doesn't a small pulldown resistor satisfy the issue of grounding floating values?

Comment: Did you consider the power loss if a signal applies a voltage? BTW, 1MOhm is not _extremely_ large, tens or hundreds of MOhm are. ;-)

Comment: R1 helps dampen oscillation if the input is a low-impedance driver and R2 provides a galvanic connection to ground so that, if otherwise left alone, the gate leaks stored charge and will eventually find itself grounded in a managed way.

Comment: Linking this post, helps clear up why the resistor used isn't even higher: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/508330/how-does-a-pull-down-prevent-a-false-1-in-a-pin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideia is to do not consume so much current from the source. For example, if you're using an 5V microcontroller, given an  1k resistor, each pin would consume 5 mA when in HIGH state. Now imagine 10 or 20 pins at same time, your micro would be driving 50 - 100 mA.

In many cases it's a 10k resistor.

Comment: Thanks bruh, I've been trying to understand this for days, and that simple statement  helped a bunch.